# How to fix this error while creating superuser?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am facing this error when I run this command:

```
heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
```

I tried running `makemigrations` and then `migrate` which works fine but I still get this error.

> You have 13 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
>   Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user

edit:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
```

}

```
import dj_database_url

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Comment: I think that your settings file is also missing the proper configurations to read DB config from env variables. That's where heroku stores that information.

Comment: "I tried running makemigrations and then migrate"—how, exactly? `manage.py makemigrations` should only be run on your development machine, but `manage.py migrate` should be run locally and on Heroku. Have you run `manage.py migrate` on Heroku, e.g. via `heroku run`?

Comment: @Chris I did this: heroku run python manage.py makemigrations and heroku run python manage.py migrate

Comment: @akki, there should never be a reason for you to run `makemigrations` on Heroku. By the time your code has been deployed there shouldn't be any model changes to generate migrations. What was the result of running `makemigrations` on Heroku?

Comment: Also, as Alex pointed out you can't use SQLite on Heroku. You _must_ use a client-server database like PostgreSQL (which is provided out of the box). Please [edit] your question and show us the database section of your `settings.py`.

Comment: @Chris I have updated the question. Also, when I run `makemigrations` , the output is 'No changes detected'

Comment: @Chris Also, I ran this `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`

Comment: @akki, for some reason your database settings aren't getting updated (there's a `sqlite3.OperationalError` in your error output). (a) Does [`heroku config`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#view-current-config-var-values) show a `DATABASE_URL` value starting with `postgres://`? (Please _don't_ post its value here. That value contains your database credentials.) (b) If you run [`heroku run manage.py shell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#shell), then `from django.conf import settings; print(settings.DATABASES)` do you see your expected `default`?

Comment: @Chris (a) yes, it does show `postgres://` . (b) this is the output i get: `{'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': '/app/db.sqlite3', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None}}}`

Comment: @akki, that doesn't look right. Are there any mentions of `DATABASES` in your `settings.py` after the `dj_database_url` stuff? Are you using multiple config files?